# SSL connection with Apache Active MQ

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

I am trying to use SSL for Apache Active MQ - but it fails.

My example works fine with "tcp://localhost:61616" - but fails with "ssl://localhost:61616"

```
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setUseJmx(true);
    broker.addConnector(ssl://localhost:61616);
    broker.start();
```

My console shows (with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl) tons of the same log messages:
....

```
ActiveMQ Transport Server: ssl://localhost:61616, called closeSocket()
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
ActiveMQ Transport Server: ssl://localhost:61616, called closeSocket()
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
```

....

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html) on the ActiveMQ website for using SSL.  You need to setup the keystore and truststore appropriately so that client and server and negotiate over SSL to establish trust.  You might want to also look at the SSL unit tests in the ActiveMQ source for some more insight into how to setup the BrokerService object with an SSL transport.